# Uncertainty about the use of ngInclude

Tags: angularjs

I render recursive template with ngInclude. Here is my code:

```
<!--
    definitionsRenderer.html
-->
<ul data-ng-if="currentLoc.definitions && templateIsloaded">
    <li ng-repeat="definition in currentLoc.definitions">
        {{definition.text}}
    </li>
</ul>
<ul data-ng-if="templateIsloaded">
    <li ng-repeat="loc in currentLoc.loc" ng-include="'./partials/definitionsRenderer.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

I need code to be executed asynchronous. So for scope of every included template 
I want to have a variable - templateIsloaded with value false by default. When template is loaded and rendered it value to be true. How do that?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have separate $scope for each of recursive called includes you can simply add `ng-controller`.

```
<li ng-repeat="loc in currentLoc.loc" ng-controller="definitionsRendererCtrl" ng-include="'./partials/definitionsRenderer.html'"></li>
```

Comment: If I could I would give you more of a plus.